# Refactor a join on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with a query of mine and how it's being joined. I need to pull some data from multiple tables in regards to CSR agents and the number of dealers they are associated with.

As shown below, I need to return a number of daily contact records for each user as well as a number of dealers associated with that number. Eventually I need to use a formula made from these 1 values, but I can do that with no problem I'm just having an issue getting the two values appropriately.

Currently, I'm getting the same number for both count values, where they should be different.

**The code:**

```
    SELECT 
          c.user AS UserID,
        COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDailyContacts, -- number of records in contact_events for this user
        COUNT(d.csr) AS NumberOfDealerContacts, -- number of dealers associated with this user
      FROM contact_events c
        JOIN users u
          ON c.user = u.id
        JOIN dealers d
          ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
        LEFT JOIN attr_list al
          ON d.csr = al.data
      GROUP BY UserID;
```

**The fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd375/1

**Desired output:**

```
      12345 |  2 |  3
      23456 |  2 |  6
      34567 |  2 |  2
      45678 |  2 |  2
      56789 |  2 |  5
      67890 |  2 |  2
      78911 |  2 |  4
```

But currently the fiddle is giving me all 2's for both columns.

The table structure for these tables sucks but it's what I'm given currently. The problem is that the contact events table uses the user ID for the CSR, where the dealer table associates by the 'data' value on the attribute_list table. So I basically have to say:

> If the user ID In the `contact_events` table matches the `user_id` for a given `data` field in `attr_list`, show dealers associated with that user.

Hopefully the fiddle makes this a little more clear but I'll answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Try using `COUNT(DISTINCT d.csr)`

Comment: Why are you joining with `attr_list`? You never use anything from that table.

Comment: I had actually tried this earlier as well, but even trying it now it just shows '1' for all records

Comment: @Barmar I am, the dealer table has a CSR column which contains those values. That's the only association we have between dealer and csr, the user id can't be used there.

Comment: `COUNT(d.csr)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` unless `d.csr` can be `NULL`.

Comment: Then I think that count is my problem. I want the first count to be the number of ```contact_events``` records for that user, but the ```count(d.csr)``` is where I'm looking to equate the dealers.csr field to the attr_list.data field and get the number of dealers associated with that user. So Perhaps I'm counting the wrong data

Comment: @Barmar maybe I should use a select sub query instead of a count there, I'm just not sure of the best way to go about it with the number of unnecessary table joins I have to have

Comment: Could you clarify what `NumberOfDealerContacts` is supposed to be counting? I can't find 3 of anything related to user 12345 in the sqlfiddle data, or 6 related to 23456.

Comment: Yes, a subquery is usually needed when summing or counting with multiple joins. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199736/a-count-for-each-join-optimisation

Comment: @Barmar it should be counting dealers from the 'dealers' table. If you look at my insert on the fiddle, you can see that the records are there, but the letters in the 'data' field are related to the 12345,23456 etc. user IDs in the attr_list table

Comment: Do you need `AND c.user_id = al.user_id` in the `attr_list` JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery that joins `attr_list` with `dealers` to get the number of dealers per user.

```
select 
    c.user as UserID,
    count(*) as NumberOfDailyContacts,
    al.NumberOfDealerContacts
From contact_events c
join users u
on c.user = u.id
join dealers d
on c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
left join (
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts
  FROM attr_list AS al
  JOIN dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
  GROUP BY user_id) AS al
ON al.user_id = c.user
GROUP BY UserID
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd375/87)

Comment: This seems to be the best option, thank you! The fiddle works great. It's not quite perfect on my database but it's because of how some of the data is managed so I can get around that based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your joins were out of order, which caused your counts to get messed up. Here's what it should be, no subqueries needed:

```
SELECT
    u.id                          AS UserID
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)         AS NumberOfDailyContacts
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT d.dealer_num) AS NumberOfDealerContacts
FROM users               u
LEFT JOIN attr_list      al ON u.id = al.user_id
LEFT JOIN dealers        d ON d.csr = al.data
LEFT JOIN contact_events c ON c.user = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: The order of joins doesn't have any effect on the results. joining is associative and commutative.

Comment: `[user]` is T-SQL syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: But your query does get the correct result in his fiddle (after fixing the syntax): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd375/109

Comment: The more important difference is changing from `count(c.csr)` to `count(distinct d.dealer_num)`

Comment: @Barmar For `INNER JOIN`s, you're correct, the order doesn't matter. But for `OUTER JOIN`s the order does matter.

Comment: @BillStidham, take a look at the OP's sqlfiddle. He defines the `user` table with only a single column, `id`.

Comment: @BillStidham, if you mean removing the distinct on `COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)`, you are incorrect. Doing that yields results that don't match the OP's desired output.