# MYSQL; I need to JOIN 2 queries with the same table but different values

Tags: mysql

I need to create a query with different values but using the same tables, this is the example of my tables

**Table 1 - applications**

```
ID | Applications
 1 |    Product1
 2 |    Product2
 3 |    Product3
 4 |    Product4
 5 |    Product5
```

**Table 2 - Survey_result**

```
ID |  application_id | completed_dt
1  |        5        |  2021-02-01
2  |        5        |  2021-02-01
3  |        3        |  2021-02-01
4  |        1        |  2021-02-01
5  |        1        |  2021-02-01
```

**Table 3   survey_result_questions**

```
id | survey_result_id | questions_id | result
1  |        2         |       2      |   1
2  |        2         |       2      |   2
3  |        1         |       2      |   5
4  |        3         |       2      |   3
5  |        2         |       2      |   4
6  |        5         |       2      |   3
7  |        4         |       2      |   1
8  |        4         |       2      |   5
9  |        3         |       2      |   4
10 |        2         |       2      |   5
```

And this my query now:

```
select * from (
    select distinct(survey_result.application_id) as Applications, survey_result.completed_dt, count(survey_result.id) AS TotalSurveys 
    from survey_result 
    left join applications ON survey_result.application_id = applications.id
    left join survey ON survey_result.survey_id = survey.id
    left join survey_result_questions ON survey_result_questions.survey_result_id = survey_result.id
    where completed_dt >= '2021-02-01' and survey_result_questions.questions_id = 2 
    Group BY Applications
) as A
join (
    select count(survey_result.id) AS Satisfied 
    from survey_result 
    left join applications ON survey_result.application_id = applications.id
    left join survey ON survey_result.survey_id = survey.id
    left join survey_result_questions ON survey_result_questions.survey_result_id = survey_result.id
    where completed_dt >= '2021-02-01' and survey_result_questions.questions_id = 2 and 
    survey_result_questions.result IN (4,5)
) as B
```

My issue are next:
In the first part of the query I want to get the count of total number of surveys group by Application_ID, this to get for example for Application ID  1,  totalsurveys = 4 or  something like this, this working correctly, but in the second part of the query I want to get the same information but just for the survey_result_questions.result 4 and 5, and I can't,  I get a big number and not the number that I Expected, check the Image 1 that I share.

**Result with error on Satisfied column**

[image: Result with error on Satisfied column]

If I separate the query, this Working that I expected, but when I join again, not working

**Query just for satisfied**

[image: Query Satisfied]

Thanks for your help!!!

**UPDATE**

Here the updated query and images but is not working =(

```
select * from(select survey_result.application_id as Applications, survey_result.completed_dt, count(survey_result.id) AS TotalSurveys from survey_result 
left join applications ON survey_result.application_id = applications.id
left join survey ON survey_result.survey_id = survey.id
left join survey_result_questions ON survey_result_questions.survey_result_id = survey_result.id
where completed_dt >= '2021-02-01' and survey_result_questions.questions_id = 2
Group BY Applications
) as A
join 
(select distinct(survey_result.application_id) as Applications, count(survey_result.id) AS Satisfied from survey_result 
left join applications ON survey_result.application_id = applications.id
left join survey ON survey_result.survey_id = survey.id
left join survey_result_questions ON survey_result_questions.survey_result_id = survey_result.id
where completed_dt >= '2021-02-01' and survey_result_questions.questions_id = 2   and survey_result_questions.result IN (4,5)
) as B
```

**Updated Query, see that I get 4041 for all the rows on Satisfied and not the numbers that I expected**
[image: Updated Query]

Comment: You don't need to use `DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`, since `GROUP BY` ensures there will just be one row for each application.

Comment: The first subquery has `and` with nothing after it. The second subquery has two `and` in a row.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is also not a function, it doesn't modify a single column. It applies to the entire select list.

Comment: And you are actually doing a Cartesian plan on both queries (provided that the fixes are done).

Comment: @Barmar sorry I remove the and, but this is not the issue... is an  error when I copy the query here

Comment: The second subquery has no `GROUP BY`, so it just returns the total count for all the rows combined. I don't see how you could ever have gotten 5 rows when running it separately.

Comment: @Barmar and If I remove the distinct, I get a lot of rows...

Comment: You still have *survey_result_questions.questions_id = 2 **and 
    and** survey_result_questions.result* in the second subquery.

Comment: @BetoA.Lien That's impossible. If you have `GROUP BY Applications` you will only get 1 row for each application in that subquery.

Comment: I know it's not the issue, because the query won't even run with those syntax errors. But if you're making those mistakes when copying here, you might be making other mistakes that actually affect the results. Use cut and paste instead of retyping, then we can be sure you're showing us the real query.

Comment: The second subquery by itself should just return 1 row, not 5 rows. Please show the actual query that returns those 5 rows.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199736/a-count-for-each-join-optimisation) is probably part of the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I update the post with the query without the distinct on the first  subquery, and   add the distinct to the second subquery, But is not the numbers that I expected =(

Comment: The secoind subquery is still missing `GROUP BY Applications`, so it just returns 1 row that gets the total count of all applications.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query