# How to count all rows with multiple table joins and where conditions?

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have the following tables:

```
create table loans
(
    id int null,
    status int null,
    user_id int null
);

INSERT INTO loans VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (2, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (3, 1, 1);

create table deals
(
    id int null,
    status int null,
    user_id int null
);

INSERT INTO deals VALUES (2, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO deals VALUES (3, 0, 1);

create table listings
(
    id int null,
    status int null,
    user_id int null
);

INSERT INTO listings VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO listings VALUES (2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO listings VALUES (3, 1, 1);
```

And have the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS active_items
FROM loans
    LEFT JOIN deals ON deals.user_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.user_id = 1
WHERE
  loans.status = 1
  AND deals.status = 1
  AND listings.status = 1
  AND loans.user_id = 1
```

The goal is to count all the rows where each table item has a status of 1, leaving out any that have a status of 0. My query which I have made seems to only  return 0 all the time and I do not understand why? How can I query the database so I can find each loan, deal and listing which has a status of 1 and returns in one total called `active_items`? Why does my query not work?

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g9CoA9CdDujqzG4ZpgmJXh/1

The output for `active_items` is expected to be 5.

Comment: `ON deals.user_id = loans.user_id` and do same for the next join

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199736/a-count-for-each-join-optimisation regarding aggregation when you have multiple joins.

Comment: @isaace Since all the tables are filtered to `user_id = 1`, it's effectively the same as joining on the `user_id` column.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @Barmar https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g9CoA9CdDujqzG4ZpgmJXh/0 The output should be `active_items` = 6

Comment: All your `INSERT` queries are into `loans`, the other tables are empty.

Comment: When I fix the inserts, the result I get is 6.

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eKnEFL65F8aUq1xrPxwtCe/0

Comment: @Barmar My bad, I have updated my fiddle, sorry about that. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g9CoA9CdDujqzG4ZpgmJXh/1

Comment: Now you have no deals with status=1

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I think that is the problem, sometimes there might not be any?

Comment: Is that a problem? If you only want to count when all the tables have status 1, you should get 0 in that case.

Comment: @Barmar I need to find the total of rows where there the status is 1, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Maybe you should use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`?

Comment: Or do 3 separate `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries and then add them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `JOIN` for this, since you're not relating the tables to each other. Just do 3 separate queries and add the counts.

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM loans
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM deals
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM listings
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 1
) AS x
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2xNZWnr9xxC36kgg7JBVpJ/0)

Comment: This has solved my issue, is this also ok for performance?

Comment: As long as the tables have appropriate indexes, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear to me what you are trying to check.
But if I understand it correctly, I think the problem you have, is you are only checking for the user_id = 1, which might not have status 1 in all the tables (I really can't be sure without seeing your data).
I think you want to do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS active_items
FROM loans
    INNER JOIN deals ON deals.user_id = loans.user_id
    INNER JOIN listings ON listings.user_id = loans.user_id
WHERE
  loans.status = 1
  AND deals.status = 1
  AND listings.status = 1
```

Comment: I am trying to count all the rows which have a status of 1 for the user_id of 1. This does not work for me. I have attached a DB Fiddle with some sample data and expect outcome .

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my DB fiddle, the expected outcome should be 5: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g9CoA9CdDujqzG4ZpgmJXh/1