# Mysql multiple many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, eager-loading

I have an attributes table that has many to many relations with groups table through ( attribute_groups ) pivot table.
AND the same for locals through ( attribute_labels ) pivot table .AND the same for choices through ( attribute_choices ) pivot table .

I want to get all attributes together ( eager-loading ) with all groups/labels/choices if there is a relation.

what I did is this :

```
select a.* ,
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', g.id,'name', g.name)) as groups
    ,JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id", al.local_id, "abbreviation",l.abbreviation,"name", al.label)) as locals
    ,JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', ac.id,"name", ac.name)) as choices,
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from attribute_groups ag where ag.attribute_id = a.id) groups_count,
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from attribute_labels al where al.attribute_id = a.id) labels_count,
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from attribute_choices ac where ac.attribute_id = a.id) choices_count
    FROM attributes a
    left join attribute_groups ag on a.id = ag.attribute_id
    left join groups g on g.id = ag.group_id
    left join attribute_labels al on a.id = al.attribute_id
    left join locals l on l.id = al.local_id
    left join attribute_choices ac on a.id = ac.attribute_id
    group by a.id
    order by a.id desc limit 10000
```

But unlikely it duplicates the relationships if I have 3 groups in relation and 3 choices and 2 labels
the groups/choices/labels get doubled to be 8 with repeated data.
because I have 3 left joins .
also I have null values for the relations

what is the best approach to eager load the relationships in MySQL?

[image: This is a sample result]

Comment: This is similar to the problem of getting incorrect `COUNT()` and `SUM()` when you join multiple tables. The solution is to join with subqueries that aggregate their respective column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199736/a-count-for-each-join-optimisation for example.

Comment: 675k replying to me , I got honored @Barmar